# Unnecessary output in while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a loop so that if a user enters a string it asks them for an integer, and it's working fine  except for outputting one line from earlier code. Don't know how to get rid of it.

```
while True : #loops input 
    userAge = raw_input("please enter your age: ")
    if  (userAge > 18) : #outputs based on age input 
        print "Congrats, you're an adult."
        continue 
    elif userAge <= 0 :
        print "You got a computer in that womb?"
        continue
    elif userAge <= 5 :   
        print "You're a toddler, get off the computer!"
        continue
    elif userAge <= 10:
        print "You're a child!"
        continue
    elif userAge <= 12:
        print "You're a preteen, go listen to fall out boy."
        continue
    elif userAge > 12:
        print "You're a teen!"
        continue
    try :
        userAge = int(userAge) 
    except ValueError :
        print ("Please enter an integer you dummy!")
        continue
    else : 
        break
```

the output when someone puts in a string looks like this:

congrats you're an adult
put in an integer you dummy! 
please enter your age:

I want to get rid of congrats you're an adult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True : #loops input 
  userAge = raw_input("please enter your age: ")
  try :
      userAge = int(userAge) 
  except ValueError :
      print ("Please enter an integer you dummy!")
      continue
  if  (userAge > 18) : #outputs based on age input 
      print "Congrats, you're an adult."
      continue 
  elif userAge <= 0 :
      print "You got a computer in that womb?"
      continue
  elif userAge <= 5 :   
      print "You're a toddler, get off the computer!"
      continue
  elif userAge <= 10:
      print "You're a child!"
      continue
  elif userAge <= 12:
      print "You're a preteen, go listen to fall out boy."
      continue
  elif userAge > 12:
      print "You're a teen!"
      continue
  else : 
      break
```

Try something like this!

The problem is that the `if` statement evaluate string according to their ASCII value, so every char will be true for one of the `if..elif` statements

Answer (score 0):

You should put the

```
try...except...else
```

statement that converts the userAge srting to integer before the actual check of the userAge in the

```
if...elif
```

statement

Answer (score 0):

There are two functions to get user input in python, called `input` and `raw_input`. `raw_input` doesn't evaluate the data and returns `string`. `input` will evaluate whatever you entered and the result of evaluation will be returned.

Decimal value of characters '0' (48),'1' (49),'2' (50),... are all larger than 18 so the first `if` in your code evaluates to true.

So try:

```
userAge = input("please enter your age: ")
```